# fullcalendar background events resourceIds misconfiguring when events drops

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I have 3 grouped events (with same groupId), one of it is a background event filling 3 resouces (resourceIds:["res1", "res2", "res3"]):

[image]

when i move the events along the same resource, they move at same time, which is perfect.

The problem is when i move the event to other resource, the background events changes resourceIds, and looks like is loosing the resource where the events comes from and just keep the current resourceId:

[image]

[image]

When i change from resource 1 to resource 2, the background event in resource 1 gets lost, and the same when i cange from 2 to 3.

Is there any way to fix event background to three resources grouped with other events. What i want is to show time where cannot overlap events.

Thanks

Comment: The question introduces the problem on the UI level, but we need the code to fix the behavior.

Comment: As well as providing [relevant code and data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), also please state which version of fullCalendar you are using

Answer (score 0):

I'm using V5.

The code i'm using is this:

```js
    var d = new Date();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var hour = d.getHours();
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();

    var strDate = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
    var strTime = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour + ':' + (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes;

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
            scrollTime: strTime,
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineThreeDay,resourceTimelineWeek'
            },
            views: {
                resourceTimelineDay: {
                    buttonText: '15 min',
                    slotDuration: '00:15'
                },
                resourceTimelineThreeDay: {
                    type: 'resourceTimeline',
                    duration: {days: 3},
                    buttonText: '3 days'
                },
                resourceTimelineWeek: {
                    type: 'resourceTimeline',
                    duration: {days: 7},
                    buttonText: 'Week'
                }
            },
            aspectRatio: 1.5,
            initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
            editable: true,
            nowIndicator: true,
            resourceAreaWidth: '300px',
            resourceAreaColumns: [
                {
                    group: true,
                    field: 'building',
                    labelText: 'C'
                },
                {
                    field: 'title',
                    labelText: 'T'
                }
            ],
            resourceGroupField: 'groupdId',
            resources: [
                {"id": "BLANCO_1", "groupdId": 'BLANCO', "building": "Blanco", "title": "C1"},
                {"id": "BLANCO_2", "groupdId": 'BLANCO', "building": "Blanco", "title": "C2"},
                {"id": "NEGRO_1", "groupdId": 'NEGRO', "building": "Negro", "title": "C1"},
                {"id": "NEGRO_2", "groupdId": 'NEGRO', "building": "Negro", "title": "C2"},
                {"id": "NEGRO_3", "groupdId": 'NEGRO', "building": "Negro", "title": "C3"}
            ],
            eventOrder: "groupId",
            events: [
                {
                    resourceId: "NEGRO_1",
                    constraint: {
                        resourceIds: ['NEGRO_1', 'NEGRO_2', 'NEGRO_3']
                    },
                    groupId: "NEGRO_1",
                    title: "Ref",
                    durationEditable: false,
                    backgroundColor: "orange",
                    borderColor: "orange",
                    start: strDate + "T13:00:00",
                    end: strDate + "T14:00:00"
                },
                {
                    groupId: "NEGRO_1",
                    durationEditable: false,
                    resourceIds: ['NEGRO_1', 'NEGRO_2', 'NEGRO_3'],
                    start: strDate + "T13:00:00",
                    end: strDate + "T14:00:00",
                    display: 'background',
                    color: '#FFD3D3'
                },
                {
                    resourceId: "NEGRO_1",
                    constraint: {
                        resourceIds: ['NEGRO_1', 'NEGRO_2', 'NEGRO_3']
                    },
                    groupId: "NEGRO_1",
                    title: "Con",
                    durationEditable: false,
                    backgroundColor: "green",
                    borderColor: "green",
                    start: strDate + "T13:00:00",
                    end: strDate + "T15:30:00"
                },
            ]
        });
        calendar.setOption('height', '100%');
    
        calendar.render();
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.0.0/main.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 
<div class="m-portlet m-portlet--mobile" m-portlet="true">
            <div class="m-portlet__head">
                <div class="m-portlet__head-caption">
                </div>
                <div class="m-portlet__head-tools">
                    <ul class="m-portlet__nav">
                        <li class="m-portlet__nav-item">
                            <a href="#" m-portlet-tool="fullscreen"
                               class="m-portlet__nav-link m-portlet__nav-link--icon"
                               aria-describedby="tooltip_exohonui1y"><i class="la la-expand"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="m-portlet__body" style="height: 700px;">
                <div id='calendar'></div>
            </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.0.0/main.min.js"></script>
```